# Reflection of protected member of a class

Tags: c#, reflection

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Reflection

{
    class Test
    {
        protected void methodname()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("in the world of the reflection"));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            Test aTest = new Test();
            MethodInfo mInfoMethod = typeof(Reflection.Test).GetMethod("methodname", eFlags);
            mInfoMethod.Invoke(aTest, null);

        }
    }
}
```

As per the msdn BindingFlags.Nonpublic is used to access the non private members. If I use only this enum the Getmethod returns null value. But if use the enum - Instance and nonpublic the required method is called. What is the difference between these two. When I have to use instance and public/nonpublic combination.

Comment: This appears to be a change in .Net 4.0: I have a similar code that works perfectly in .Net 3.5, but I had to change the flag from `NonPublic` to `Public` to get it to work on 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the documentation of `GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx):

> You must specify either `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BindingFlags.Static` in order to get a return.

`Instance`/`Static` and `Public`/`NonPublic` specify two different things and you have to specify both in order to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the enum, the default is used. If you do, you have to specify both:

- Public or NonPublic (or both)
- Static or Instance (or both)

(See the note in the remarks section on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)